# Tag autocomplete in careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, jobs, javascript

I was editing my Careers 2.0 profile, and I tried to add a new tag to `dislikes`.  I typed a few letters, and the spinner kept spinning, and the list of tags never appeared.

I opened my console and saw

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] has no method 'split'
```

The AJAX call to `/filter/tags` completes and returns data, but it seems someone is trying to `split` an array.

Comment: So many objects.

Comment: Tag handling on careers is getting reworked, which includes fixing this and similar bugs.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Traverse *ALL* the objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed, thanks for the report.

Comment: Thanks, now I can add more things I don't like to my careers profile :-)